# Always getting below error in some of my Web Servers:

Tags: sql, web-services

I am getting below error in some of my webserver. I don't know what is happening in my server, whether this is SQL DB related or Web server related.

> Message::Save- Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Norman.Message.Save(Int32 nSiteID, String sBody, Int32 nUserID, String sUserIP)

Please help me how to trouble shoot.

Comment: The queries take too long to complete, so SQL Server aborts the transaction. Look at optimizing these queries and your database.

Comment: Sounds like your sql server is unreachable. Can you `ping` it?

Comment: This exception appears to be coming from the Command's execute statement, so the connection is already open (and server reachable). as @Oded said, we would need to see the SQL Queries themselves and some info on the table being queried. Would you be able to post these?

Comment: See exactly i don't know which info from table cause this issue. How to identify that which is causing this issue any tools.

Answer (score 0):

are you using some kind of ORM?? I am guessing there is some row lock being held by one of your transactions on the tables and that is why you are seeing timeouts when there are selects being run on the same table.

I would take a closer look at all your write actions and make sure that they occur at the end of the http request and you avoid large processing after writing into the db especially if you are relying on auto-incrementing ids etc. which locks the table.

Comment: How to identify this issue, i mean how to know what causing this issue.

Comment: Hi How to identify that issue and how to fix?